# Where is Emulator Control View in IntelliJ?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

In Eclipse you can change your simulated location using the Emulator Control view (Window > Show View > Other... > Android > Emulator Control).

Image:
[image]

Where can I find this view/tab in IntelliJ?

PS. I know that I can use DDMS, but I wonder if there is a tab in IntelliJ, like there is in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such option in IDEA yet. We [have a request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-50401) to add dedicated DDMS tool window, feel free to vote.

Comment: Well it would be nice to have it, but I guess you have more important things to add :). So I'll just use DDMS. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Click the Tools----Android -----

There you will see the DDMS option that opens in a separate window. which is cool... i need not switch perspectives like in eclipse..

Answer (score 2):

Actually DDMS is not feature of Eclipse or IntelliJ. It tool that can be run separately.

It can be found in  android-sdk-windows\tools (where android-sdk-windows is dirrectory with all android stuff on your disk)